# GitLab Pages Deployment Fail: Create-React-App w/ Router

Tags: deployment, react-router, gitlab, gitlab-ci, create-react-app

I have this simple prototype (basically a dummy app) built with create-react-app and libraries react-router-dom and material-ui. I'm trying to deploy to GitLab pages but the build fails every time.

Here's the prototype: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-darkness-7ol93

The `gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
# Using the node alpine image to build the React app
image: node:alpine

# Announce the URL as per CRA docs
variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: /

# Cache node modules - speeds up future builds
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules

# Name the stages involved in the pipeline
stages:
- deploy

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install # Install all dependencies
    - npm run build --prod # Build for prod
    - cp public/index.html public/404.html 
    - mv public _public # CRA and gitlab pages both use the public folder. Only do this in a build pipeline.
    - mv build public # Move build files to public dir for Gitlab Pages
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public # The built files for Gitlab Pages to serve
  only:
    - master # Only run on master branch
```

Failure Output:

```
npm ERR! prototype@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the prototype@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-24T19_12_35_870Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I've tried myriad solutions including using HashRouter, adding a basepath prop, specifying different versions of node in the gitlab-ci.yml, and adding the "homepage" field to package.json.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does `node:alpine` image contain `create-react-app` CLI? After I created a react app and check its `package.json`, In `scripts` part I saw `"build": "react-scripts build"`. So when you run `npm run build` it follows `react-scripts build` command, which is a part of `create-react-app` CLI tool. Thus if `node:alpine` image does contain `create-react-app`, it might cause to above error.

Comment: @AmirMohammadDadkhah Are you saying that if node:alpine contains create-react-app, the pipeline will try to build twice? Or am I misunderstanding why the error is caused... Thanks.